# Forms/AD Authentication with Sharepoint

Tags: security, sharepoint, forms-authentication

All,

I'm configuring Sharepoint to use forms authentication with LDAP/Active Directory. I'm new to Sharepoint, so if this is obvious, please point me in the right direction.

Whenever I attempt to log in with a bad account or password, I get the very friendly (and correct) error message,

> The server could not sign you in. Make
>   sure your user name and password are
>   correct, and then try again.

... which implies that Sharepoint is able to communicate with AD. If I log in with a valid account, I get a page that says:

[alt text http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/6053/sharepointerror.png](http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/6053/sharepointerror.png)

(I added the grey bar to cover up the login name)

Any suggestions? The account I'm logging in with is an administrator and has been granted full control in central administration.

Also, interesting note: If I click the "sign in as a different user" link, and attempt to sign in using with the same credentials I just used, the site just redirects back to the login page, with no error or status message. If I then manually enter the site url, it again shows the "Error: Access Denied" page. Argh.

Comment: Is the issue to do with a masterpage or similar not being given the correct permissions/remaining unpublished.

Answer (score 1):

Go to site action of the actual site and add user in the format of
:loginid
It should resolve and show it underlined then try login in back to application that should fix it.
Your AD connection is working fine just need to add to sharepoint users list

yourprovider:userid 
Yourprovider name is the name you gave to the user provider in web config

And you can add this user from parent site that is windows protected and you have all

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's sharepoint site security issue. 
I'm getting the same error when trying to enter Site Settings page with a user that has a lack of permissions.
If you have at least one user that can access the Site Settings page, I suggest you to go to Site Actions/Site Settings/Users and Permissions/People and grops then click New button and add a user from AD to an appropriate group, eg. Team Site Members.

Answer (score 0):

You have made connection with Ad and its working fine. So that you got error, when you try to login with invalid user id.

But you have missed one step in above scenario.

You need to give the permission for all AD users in your SharePoint site. The better way is to create a user group in AD (it may already there) which included all the users and add this user group in your SharePoint site with read permission.